# Friends and nested classes

Tags: c++, class, friend, friend-class

Ok I'm totally frazzled on this. Code is begin to swim around the screen...must sleep.

So! Ok, troubled by nested classes and friends.

here is the pseudo-code

```
   class A{
     public:
          //constructor
          // member functions
     private:
          class B{
          //private
          int a();
          };

          class C{
          //private
          int b();
          };
   };
```

So once an object of type A has been created, I would like it to access a() and b(). I know that I have to use a friend function for this. So where should I put friend class A. Is that the right expression?.

Comment: Do you call  `b` and `C` constructors when you are instantiating from `A`?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to access `a()` and `b()` from within class `A` you need to place the `friend` declaration inside of class `B` and class `C`. However, `a()` and `b()` are not members of class `A` so you cannot access them in the way you are thinking. Instead you also need to add *forwarding* functions to `A`.

```
class A
{
public:
    //constructor
    // member functions
private:
    class B
    {
        //private
        int a();

        friend A;    // <-- make A a friend
    };

    class C
    {
        //private
        int b();

        friend A;    // <-- make A a friend
    };

public:

    // forwarding function for a
    int a()
    {
        return bdata_.a();
    }

    // forwarding function for b
    int b()
    {
        return cdata_.b();
    }

private:
    B bdata_;
    C cdata_;
};
```

Comment: in my main function I use this code to attempt to access a() and b()  objectA->a() however it still does work? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `a()` and `b()` are _not_ members of class `A`. They are members of the classes they are declared in.

Comment: its still not working. I tried using an accessor function to access the private data members in Class A but the program complains of an unlawful conversion. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Josh why don't you just post a minimal code example showing what you are trying to do?

Comment: GOTCHA! many thanks, just had to create a new accessor function and make it a public data member.

Comment: sorry, public member function.

Comment: sorry, missed adding public. Answer should be complete now